# Not getting push notification from GCM eventhough response is success

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want push notification by using GCM, all things are done properly, like `API` key & others.

I'm getting following success message, but not getting notification on mobile(device id is also proper, also tried on different divices)

```
 {"multicast_id":6811225836747189127,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1395652805845432%ae8ef3eff9fd7ecd"}]}
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Thanx in advance

manifest code``

```
<permission android:name="com.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />  <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.demo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.demo.GCMIntentService" />                    ``
```

Comment: You have to include any relevant code, otherwise it's not possible to help.

Comment: Can you please post your android code.

Comment: I'm using code from this link http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: 'public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{

 static String regis_id;
 
 private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

 public GCMIntentService()
 {
  super(SENDER_ID);
 }

 @Override
 public void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
 {
  Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
  displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
  ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
  this.setRegId(registrationId);
 }
}'

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. You should check your "send id" should be something like this in your code:

**String SENDER_ID = "1090629393827";**

that number is your project id.

...Also try to allow any IP on your google project page and check your API Key. For some reaseon sending data trought a browser i had to use the **BROWSER API KEY** no the **SERVER API KEY**.

and finally if you are using a emulator check you firewall setting!

sorry for my english it's not my first language.